# Im integrating GSAP from Greenshock, in my REACT Web App. I get an error: Quint is not defined?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gsap

I have downloaded all the packages for Tweenlite.  `npm install` and and `yarn add` all my `REACT` and node `dependencies` . For Some reason an error in the console tells me: `Quint is undefined` Heres the code that its specifically pointing to:

```
function setupParallax(){
  document.addEventListener('mousemove',(event)=>{
  let x=event.pageX;
  let y=event.pageY;

TweenLite.to(parallax,1,{
  x:((x/canvas.width)*2)-1,
  y:((y/canvas.height)*2)-1,
  ease:Quint.easeOut,
  onUpdate:()=>{
    renderer.parallaxX=parallax.x;
    renderer.parallaxY=parallax.y;
  }
 })
});
}
```

Has anyone gone into the same problem?  Please help - THANKS in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is because TweenMax uses its own syntax for Easing.

Quint is not part of the syntax.   your choices are:

Power0
Power1
Power2
Power3
Power4
Back
Elastic
Bounce
Rough
SlowMo
Stepped
Circ
Expo
Sine
and Custom

[Use this URL to get your easing equasion](https://greensock.com/ease-visualizer)